# Print FPU registers in lldb

Tags: debugging, llvm, lldb, fpu

How do you print FPU registers using lldb?

In gdb, you would do something like `p $st0`, however doing the same in lldb results in the error: `error: use of undeclared identifier '$st0'`.

`register read st0` doesn't work either and gives the error `error: Invalid register name 'st0'.`.

Comment: Q: Have you tried `register read`? This link is a useful "cheat sheet": http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `register read --all` as suggested by `paulsm4`, I found that the name of the registers are actually `stmm0` to `stmm7` and not `st0` to `st7`.

So doing `register read stmm0 --format b` will get you the binary representation of the float.

Comment: I'm sure you know this already but you can always use shorter abbreviations for lldb commands, so in this case `re re -f b stmm0` would also work.  You can also add a command alias to your `~/.lldbinit` file if this is a commonly used sequence, e.g. `comm alias vpb register read -f b`, which would add a new command `vpb` to your lldb.

Comment: @JasonMolenda Do you know how to write to the registers as `register write stmm0 1` doesn't work.

Comment: I think you'll need to use the same uint8_t array syntax that `reg read stmm0` prints by default.  e.g. `reg write stmm1 '{0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xff 0xf0}'`