# Displaying the FPU registers in LLDB in floating point

Tags: lldb, fpu, x87

I’m trying to display the contents of a desired FPU register in floating point.  It’s very simple in GDB:

p $st0

I know that register is called stmm0 in LLDB, but I can only get it to display the ten byte in hexadecimal.  I haven’t been able to figure out how to display (cast) it as floating point like GDB does.  Surely there must be a way.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print FPU registers in lldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093585/print-fpu-registers-in-lldb)

Comment: In your case adjusted for formatting `re r stmm0 --f f`