# How to check floating point values in gdb? (assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, x87

How do I print / check floating point values in gdb?

I tried doing `fldpi` and then in gdb `print $st` and it says it's void

Im on x86 NASM

Comment: The register name you want is `$st0`, like in `info reg float`.  Or if you're using modern SSE2 scalar math instead of legacy x87, `p $xmm0.v2_double[0]` for the low scalar double of XMM0.  (Would be a duplicate of [Displaying the FPU registers in LLDB in floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61648992) except it's only that question itself that starts out with an answer to your question, and is only answered in comments.)

Comment: A few of the answers on [How to print register values in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5429137) mention ways to see all registers, which would tell you the names GCC uses for them.